# Add new column to exists table - Flask Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add new column to exists table with data.
The problem is that i dont know how to do it and i dont want to delete the whole table cause i already have data.

What should i do? how can i add another column without effect for bad my exists table

** This my table**

```
class Movies(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'movies'
id = db.Column(db.String(300), primary_key=True, unique=True)
cat_id = db.Column(db.String(300), db.ForeignKey('category.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
category = db.relationship('Category', backref='movies')
title = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
link = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
duration = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
thumb_large = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
thumb = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
embed = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
tags = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
published = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
```

Now i want to add new column which is `video_id = db.Column(db.String(250))`.
The error that i get when i try to add it is `[SQL: ALTER TABLE movies ADD COLUMN video_id VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL]`

What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

If you insert column in non empty table, **video_id** should be **nullable=True**. If it's not acceptable, you need to populate video_id by some data. For example:

```
video_id = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False, default='Some value here')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a library that can help with managing database migrations. https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

But also, if you would like to avoiding an additional dependency and aren't afraid to break something you could run the raw SQL command that the error referencing.

`ALTER TABLE movies ADD COLUMN video_id VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL`

Comment: I'm actually using Flask Migrate. my whole question base on that

Comment: Got it. Assuming you have flask-migrate wired in like the example in the documentation, all that is required should be to run the following in your command line or terminal after updating your models.

`flask db migrate -m "added video_id column"` then `flask db upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#create-a-migration-script) to solved this problem :)

However, here is how I solved :D

First, make sure you install

```
pip3 install alembic
```

Secondly,  run alembic revision to create script. In my case, I run

```
python3 app.py db revision -m 'some message'
```

Third, run alembic upgrade head. For me, I run

```
python3 app.py db upgrade head
```

Lastly, I make changes in the script (without added this to script won't work for my case)

```
def upgrade():
    op.add_column('movies', sa.Column('video_id', sa.String())

def downgrade():
    op.drop_column('movies', 'video_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually what i did is i went to pgAdmin and added new column to the table, which is not the most correct way of doing it, but it worked.